# How to access a private zone via DNS peering

Tags: google-cloud-platform, internal-dns, dns-zone, vpc-peering

Let's say I have 2 projects (A, B), each with their own VPC and VPC peering enabled between them.

Then I create a private DNS zone in project A, let's say with `.internal` as DNS name. Then I add an A record to be able to reach an instance like that: `instance-1.internal` in A.

Now I'm wondering if using DNS Peering, I can achieve to reach the instance via `instance-1.internal` in project B, I tried to create a DNS Peering Zone with B as the consumer of A, but I couldn't resolve  `instance-1.internal` in B.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that your goal is to reach an instance in VPC-A from VPC-B by its internal (to VPC-A) DNS name by dns-peering VPC-B to VPC-A.

If my understanding is correct, it is not only possible, it's the idea of dns peering. I just created a lab, where I:

- Created VPC-A in Project A
- Created VPC-B in Project B
- Created an internal DNS zone (vpc-a.internal) in VPC-A with one A record pointing to the instance in the same VPC (ip=172.16.1.209, name=instance-1)
- Created a peering DNS zone in VPC-B and pointed it to VPC-A (peering in unidirectional relationship, no need to do the same in VPC-A)
- Created an instance in VPC-B (test-instance) and dig'ed that previously created A record:

```
username@test-instance:~$ dig +short instance-1.vpc-a.internal
172.16.1.209
```

As you can see the resolution works. Please note, that DNS Peering is about being able to `resolve` names, and not about being able to `access`. If you need to `access` instance-1 in VPC-A from VPC-B then you need to establish `VPC peering` as well.

Comment: That seems to be pretty similar to what I've tried without success, in my case the projects/VPCs already exists, I'm currently using IPs to reach instances from project A in project B. dig doesn't succeed.